# lightningchart.js 3D Box Series Spectrogram, how to CustomTick Using?

Tags: lightningchart

[3D Box Series Spectrogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEUj8.png)

```
 const chart3D = lightningChart().Chart3D({
     disableAnimations: true,
     theme: Themes.lightNew,
 })
     .setTitle( '3D Box Series Spectrogram' )
     .setBoundingBox( { x: 1, y: 1, z: 2 } )
 chart3D.setCameraLocation( initialCameraLocation )
 
 
 chart3D.getDefaultAxisY()
     .setScrollStrategy( AxisScrollStrategies.expansion )
     .setInterval( 0, 100 )
     .setTitle( 'Power spectrum P(f)' )
      
 const axisX= chart3D.getDefaultAxisX()
     axisX.setTitle( 'Frequency (Hz)' )
     axisX.setStrokeStyle(emptyLine)
     axisX.setInterval(0, 256, false, true)
     var tick = axisX.setTickStrategy( AxisTickStrategies.Numeric)
        
 chart3D.getDefaultAxisZ()
     .setTitle( 'Time' )
     .setInterval( 0, -dataHistoryLength )
     .setTickStrategy( AxisTickStrategies.Empty)
     .setScrollStrategy( AxisScrollStrategies.progressive )
```

LightningChart.js Example 3D Box Series Spectrogram
xAxis AND yAxis Tick to 0,90,180,270,360 Change Way ?
chart3D getDefaultAxisX() addCustomTick is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to have X axis ticks on following values: 0, 90, 180, 270 and 360, and nowhere else.

This is currently not possible. In 3D charts, only default tick placement is available. Manual tick placement (custom ticks) is currently only available in 2D charts.

While this is a feature we would eventually be adding, it doesn't have any priority at the moment as this is the first time we hear of a user needing it. If you need it for commercial purposes then please contact us https://www.arction.com/contact/

EDIT: Dedicated feature for 3D Custom Ticks has been accepted and will be released in a minor version release 2023.

EDIT: 3D Custom Ticks have been released along side LightningChart JS v4.1.0

Comment: We are going to use it commercially
I tried to contact https://www.arction.com/contact/ but only found a .Net version of the code inquiry.

Please explain how to contact us.

Comment: Leave a contact form on that page (scroll a bit down), under "General Inquiries", and we'll get in touch shortly.

Comment: I left a general inquiry, but no response. Is there a way to check if I am registered for general inquiry?

Comment: Maybe there's some technical issue... Please directly email sales@lightningchart.com in this case.